# How do I get missing data and how do I remove holidays from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests, interpolation

I have the following problem:

I have fetched the data of different asset classes over a period of 5 years in a dataframe. Since I have to work with returns, I have converted them into returns with pct_change(). Furthermore, I have removed the weekend from the period. For this I used resample('B').asfreq() so that I only have values from Monday to Friday. I was also missing data, which I then interpolated with interpolate().

My problem now is that I still have holidays in my dataframe where the stock exchanges were closed, so there was no change in the returns. Therefore I have some 0's in my dataframe.
Does anyone know how I can best fix this problem?
I want to calculate the correlation between different asset classes.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately cannot see the picture. Have you tried subsetting like `df[df.Rate > 0]`?

Comment: No, i need a way to remove holidays from the dataframe, you got an idea?

Comment: Can you share the code you have used to remove holidays? Share a sample data (rather than your PC full screenshot) with you code snippet in the questions so that people can replicate and help you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to remove all lines which contain 0?
If so you can use `df = df.loc[(df != 0).all(1)]`